# How to access Prism's DialogService from outside ViewModels

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I want to show some dialogs from a static class, and I cannot figure out how can I access to the DialogService object that is injected into the viewmodels. Is there any way I can get it?

For the NavigationService, I expose the property in my App.xaml.cs and I can get it from everywhere in my app. I would like to do the same with the DialogService, but I can't do it like this because I don't see the service in the app.xaml.cs.

This is how do it in my App.xaml.cs for the NavigationService:

```
public INavigationService oNavigationService => NavigationService;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to show some dialogs from a static class

You don't want to do that. That `static` thing. What you want is a regular (non-`static`) class registered as singleton. This way you get injected dependencies and your problem becomes trivial.

Like:

```
internal class ThisWasStaticBefore
{
    public ThisWasStaticBefore( INavigationService navigationService )
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        _navigationService.Navigate();
    }

    private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;
}
```

and in your `Application`-class:

```
 protected void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
 {
     containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<ThisWasStaticBefore>();
 }
```

and somewhere else

```
internal class SomeConsumer
{
    public SomeConsumer( ThisWasStaticBefore theService )
    {
        _theService = theService;
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        _theService.DoStuff();
    }

    private readonly ThisWasStaticBefore _theService;
}
```

Side-note:

If you insist, you can do it the *wrong* way and keep your class static and access the service by `ContainerLocator.Container.Resolve<INavigationService>()`...

Comment: Thank you. I have been using a static class because I didn't know that I could register a singleton in the RegisterTypes as you mentioned. I'm kinda new with prism and definitely need to learn more about it.